# Is it possible to stop a Rx.Subject from emitting within a subscriber like event.stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Using `RxJS 5`, is this possible?

```
var source = new Rx.Subject();

source.map((data) => {console.log('map1'); return data;})
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('subscribe1', data);
        if(someCondition) {
            source.stop(); //????????
        }
    });

source.map((data) => {console.log('map2'); return data;})
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('subscribe2', data);
    });
```

So, when I call `source.next("Hello World");` only the first subscriber will be notified. Of course this will fail in `source.stop()` because the `stop` function does not exist but it is just to elaborate my question.

Exist a way to do this, like `event.stopPropagation` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what do you expect by stopping propagation. You can call `source.complete()` which will stop the Subject and it will never emit anything any more.

See demo: https://jsbin.com/geyucuc/3/edit?js,console

However, if you want to be able to work on "per item basis" you can't the structure you have right now because each value from `source` is emitted to both its subscribers by the Subject.

You don't have chain where the value goes like `source` => `subscribe1` => `subscribe2`.

Right now you have `source` => `subscribe1` and then `source` => `subscribe2`.

So you can make it a chain like this for example:

```
var source = new Rx.Subject();

source
    .map(item => { // wrap this
        return { value: item, stopped: false };
    })
    // your logic
    .map((data) => {
        console.log('map1', data.value);
        // do whatever here
        if (data.value == 2) {
          data.stopped = true;
        }
        return data;
    })
    .filter(item => !item.stopped) // this is your stopPropagation()
    .map((data) => {
        // do whatever here
        console.log('map2', data.value);
        return data;
    })
    .subscribe((data) => {
        // do nothing here, just construct the chain.
    });

source.next(1);
source.next(2);
```

Which prints the following:

```
map1 1
map2 1
map1 2
```

Comment: Now i'm getting the picture right. So, if `filter` return `false` the next map won't be called?

Comment: I know you explain that I don't have a chain, but, the subscribers run in the same order they subscribe, doesn't make it a chain? RxJS should provide a way to say: "hey, do not emit any more". Or, this is out of the Observable pattern?

Comment: @CastroRoy I'd be a chain if `source` send item to `subscribe1` then `subscribe1` sent it to `subscribe2`. This way `subscribe1` has control over the value it's sending. It may modify it not send it at all. On the other hand when you have `source` and two subscribers they receive the value independently on each other. If `filter()` return false the value is not propagated to the consequent oeprator.

Comment: Ok, it is not a chain, but a `sequence` exist to emit to subscribers, I was hopping that sequence could be stopped, and `filter` does not suggest it can block the item from getting to the next observer at all. Your answer is kind of a hack, but your idea help me to accomplish what I wanted. Thanks